# How do I retrieve the size of a directory from Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I would like to know how much disk space a directory is going to consume before I bring it over from the Perforce server.  I don't see any way to do this other than getting the files and looking at the size of the directory in a file manager.  This, of course, defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to get file size info from Perforce without actually getting the files?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this command, but here's how you do it:

**p4 sizes -s //depot/directory/...**

Comment: Note that `...` is crucial (I originally took it as "the rest of the path")

Answer (score 2):

[`p4 fstat`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/fstat.html)

Comment: I can get the size of a file that way, but I guess I was really more interested in getting the size of a directory (I'll edit my question). Something like "p4 dstat".

Comment: total = 0
foreach file in mydir do
  p4 fstat file
  total += size of file
done
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Combined the solutions of everybody together to get it to work.

p4 sizes -s //depot/...

If you never used the console before - you can just open Windows' CMD and type that right in there.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, it just outputs 0 for a top level directory. Seems to work fine for any child directories.

But this worked for the root of the tree:

```
p4 sizes -h -s //depot/directory/*/...
```

Added -h to print size as human readable number with nice units