# Perforce repository operations

Tags: perforce

I got a huge folder on Perforce repository, say `//myroot/foo/...`. And the tree structure looks like:

```
//myroot/foo/sub1/a/...  10MB
//myroot/foo/sub1/b/...   1GB
//myroot/foo/sub2/a/...  20MB
//myroot/foo/sub2/b/... 1.5GB
//myroot/foo/sub3/a/...  30MB
//myroot/foo/sub3/b/...   1GB
```

1. Is there any way to check the folder size like above without sync'ing `//myroot/foo` to local disk space as it takes too long.
2. When creating a new workspace, is it possible to create a mapping to exclude all "`b`" subfolder? Something like:

   -//myroot/foo/.../b/...    //myWorkSpace/foo/.../b/...

Comment: As for 2. There should be wildchar "*" but I have never tried to exclude folder like this, so it is just a guess: -//myroot/foo/*/b/... //myWorkSpace/foo/*/b/...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the size of a directory from Perforce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174322/how-do-i-retrieve-the-size-of-a-directory-from-perforce)

Comment: One question per post, please.  As for 2. [have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3103898/4228).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228/raven) mentioned, the first question has been answered:

   **p4 sizes -s //myroot/foo/...**
2. Also answered by [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228/raven) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099505/can-you-ignore-a-directory-in-p4v/3103898#3103898)